# How to start new Joomla project under same joomla installation?

Tags: joomla

I have installed XAMPP and installed Joomla under it using Bitnami Joomla installer in my local pc. I have already created a project and now I want to create a new Joomla project but can't find an option.

How do I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new folder within your current Joomla installation, extract and Joomla package there and run the installation.

What I currently tend to do is never use the root for any work. So my folder structure would look like this:

```
> xampp/wamp root
    > Joomla install 1
    > Joomla install 2
    > Joomla install 3
```

Comment: mine is c:xampp/apps/joomla and when I try to make new folder in "apps" dir i.e. "Joomla2" it gives me error

Comment: What error does it give you? Try creating a new folder inside the actual "joomla" folder

Comment: its give proprieties.ini file missing and folder does not contain valid installation of bitnami